# How to read 2 dimensional array data using Google Sheets API?

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

i'm new to Google Sheets API,
currently i am develop a system to send data to google sheets.
And while im trying to send the data, it shows error like: Invalid values [0][0]

[image: This is the error]

Below is my code line.

`

```
     $client = getClientAuth();

        $spreadsheet_ID = $this->spreadsheet->spreadsheetId; 
        
        $range = "Sheet1";

        $values = $this->sheetData;

        $this->service = new Sheets($client);


        $body = new ValueRange([
            'majorDimension' => 'ROWS',
            'values' => [array_map(function($nv) {
                return (is_null($nv)) ? "" : $nv;
              },$values)]
        ]);

        $params = ['valueInputOption' => 'RAW'];

        $insert = ['insertDataOption' => 'INSERT_ROWS'];

        //executing the request
        $data = $this->service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheet_ID, $range,
        $body, $params, $insert);
    
        return $data;
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error message and your showing script, I thought that in your situation, `$values` might be a 2-dimensional array. I think that if `$values` is a 1-dimensional array, your script works. And also, please include `'insertDataOption' => 'INSERT_ROWS'` in `$params`. So, in this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
$body = new ValueRange([
    'majorDimension' => 'ROWS',
    'values' => [array_map(function($nv) {
        return (is_null($nv)) ? "" : $nv;
      },$values)]
]);

$params = ['valueInputOption' => 'RAW'];

$insert = ['insertDataOption' => 'INSERT_ROWS'];

//executing the request
$data = $this->service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheet_ID, $range,
$body, $params, $insert);
```

#### To:

```
$body = new ValueRange([
    'majorDimension' => 'ROWS',
    'values' => array_map(function($row) {
      return array_map(function($col) {
        return (is_null($col)) ? "" : $col;
      }, $row);
    }, $values)
]);
$params = ['valueInputOption' => 'RAW', 'insertDataOption' => 'INSERT_ROWS'];
$data = $service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheet_ID, $range, $body, $params);
```

or

```
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
    'majorDimension' => 'ROWS',
    'values' => array_map(function($row) {
      return array_map(function($col) {
        return (is_null($col)) ? "" : $col;
      }, $row);
    }, $values)
]);
$params = ['valueInputOption' => 'RAW', 'insertDataOption' => 'INSERT_ROWS'];
$data = $service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheet_ID, $range, $body, $params);
```

#### Note:

- When the arrow function is used, I think that the following modification can be used.

  - From

    ```php
    'values' => array_map(function($row) {
      return array_map(function($col) {
        return (is_null($col)) ? "" : $col;
      }, $row);
    }, $values)
    ```
  - To

    ```php
    'values' => array_map(fn($row) => array_map(fn($col) => (is_null($col)) ? "" : $col, $row), $values)
    ```

Comment: Hi @Tanaike , after i try your code lines, it shows this error:

"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"9\" at 'data.values[2]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"10\" at 'data.values[2]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"11\" at 'data.values[2]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"13\" at 'data.values[2]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"14\" at 'data.values[2]'

Comment: @benzi Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In this case, I think that it is required to confirm your `$values`. Can you provide the value of `$values`? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Yes sure Mr @Tanaike. i will put it on the question section.

Comment: @benzi Thank you for replying. In this case, can you provide the value of `$values` as text?

Comment: Okay @tanaike, Here is the value of $values : array ( 0 => array ( 0 => 'HQ', 1 => 44837.0, 2 => 'SI', 3 => 'SI 00006', 4 => '0001', 5 => '0', 6 => 'Twitter', 7 => 'GS002', 8 => 'Gum Strawberry'), )

Comment: @benzi Thank you for replying. From your reply, I modified the answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Alright it works Mr @Tanaike! I have been working on this for days. Thanks to you!!

Comment: @benzi Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.